# Sharing data using an AngularJS Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, web-deployment, angularjs-service

Why does http://plnkr.co/edit/sjmRT8XOCYPW3ntEnN3N?p=preview work and http://plnkr.co/edit/Tkizktj0kx3OQmAkSH6U?p=preview not.

The only difference is the like in Cart.js `cartContent.push(product);` VS `cartContent = [{name: "Keyboard"}];`

The only difference that I can see is the Angular object ( after being created has a ) `$$hashKey` key...

I want to completely over write the object `cartContent` and have it still available to `cartBoxCtrl` and `productListCtrl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because in the second case you are overwriting the cartContent which is set as a reference to `$scope.cart` so any changes made to the `cart` is not reflected in the scope when you overwrite the content, since the $scope.cart still points to the old reference. So in your controller set the `$scope.cart` to `Cart` service and access cartContent in ng-repeat, so that the `scope.cart` now has  the reference to the Cart object itself and any changes made to its property will be reflected in the scope's property as well.

```
controller('cartBoxCtrl', function ($scope, Cart){
    $scope.cart = Cart; //<-- here 
});
```

and

```
 <li ng-repeat="product in cart.cartContent track by $index">
```

Also note the usage of track by (here i have used $index, instead you could use a unique property on the object ex:- product.id) so that list will be tracked by that instead of the angular created unique key `$$haskkey`

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jruYYO?p=preview)**

or if you want to cleanup cartContent and still keep the cartContent as reference in your `$scope.cart` then you can do:-

```
this.addProduct = function (product) {
    //Cleanup the current array and insert new item
    this.cartContent.splice(0, this.cartContent.length, product);

};
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UXrxFZ?p=preview)**

Comment: The second part of your answer is exactly what i needed :) thanks !

Comment: @michaelcurry oh explanation wasn't required? :P

Comment: Oh, it was :P It made me explain what I was doing.  Thanks you.  [Been learning Angular from scratch for the past 2 days]